# I got a bios 367 error on Computercraft

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

On my program for Computer craft that will be used in a control tower in my airport map, I got a message that looked like this:

> bios:367:[string "AirportCommand"]:15: syntax error

Here is all my code please tell me if you see any errors:

```
local Landing_open = true
rednet.open("top")

while true do

  id, message, distance = rednet.receive()

  if message == "Requesting Landing" and Landing_open == true and distance<500 then
    rednet.send(id, "Landing is granted. Please respond with Landing finished when you exit the runway.")
    Landing_open = false

   elseif message == "Requesting Landing" and distance>=500 then
     rednet,send(id, "Landing is not granted. Please try again when you are closer to the airport,")

   elseif message == "Requesting Landing" and Landing_open == false then
    rednet.send(id, "Landing is not granted. Please try again later.")

   elseif message == "Landing Finished" then
    rednet.send(id, "Roger that")
    Landing_open = true
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile and it doesn't have `AirportCommand` anywhere in it, so it can't be the source of *this* error.

Comment: It's not a "bios 367 error". It's an error intial thrown by the File "bios" in Line 367. And 'caused by File "AirportCommand" in Line 15

while the line could be misleading... Write an Answer now which should solve your problem

Comment: You have `rednet,send` instead of `rednet.send`

Comment: I see you could solve this problem (ref: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31773264/4273199 ) Why do you don't tell us how? Please accept the answer that solved your problem. Or write one yourself and accept that if you solved it alone.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: If this is your full code it can't work! you don't close your `if` nor your `while` structure.

Try to extend your code by two `end`. One closes your `if` structure and one you `while`